# How to reference a dataframe name as a string in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quandl

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import quandl

start = pd.to_datetime('2012-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')



aapl = quandl.get('WIKI/aapl.11', start_date = start, end_date= end )
csco = quandl.get('WIKI/csco.11', start_date = start, end_date= end )
ibm = quandl.get('WIKI/ibm.11', start_date = start, end_date= end )
amzn = quandl.get('WIKI/amzn.11', start_date = start, end_date= end )
```

This creates 4 data frames. I want to be able to achieve this by using a for loop.

Here is what I imagine the for loop would look like.

```
for i in [aapl,csco,ibm,amzn]:
    a = 'WIKI/'+ i + '.11'
    i = quandl.get(a, start_date=start, end_date=end)
```

I would like to be able to reference the name of the data frame as a string in the loop to perform other functions that require the name of the dataframe as a string.

Anyone help me with this or suggest an alternative approach which achieve the same result. I am hoping to be able to do this in a way that would scale to 100s of loop iterations.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Replace `[aapl,csco,ibm,amzn]` by `['aapl', 'csco', 'ibm', 'amzn']`.

Comment: And using `i` twice is confusing.

Comment: when I do this I get the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'aapl' is not defined

would you define an empty dataframe first?

Comment: you might want to consider using a dict to store the data frames in, that way you can use the same string you used to load them, if you follow Keldorn's advice. But you definitely can't save them to a string.

Comment: I think I was getting my languages mixed up, you can save the databases to i, but that's probably not what you want to do

Comment: You shouldn't use variables to refer to a bunch of objects of the same type. Use an array `dfs = [quandl.get(...), ...]`, or if you want them to have names, a dictionary. Then refer to them as `dfs[0], ...` or `dfs["aapl"], ...`. This also allows you to loop over them if you want to do the same thing to all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent to G. B.'s answer, but without dictionary comprehension in case you are not familiar with it yet.

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

start = pd.to_datetime('2012-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')

data = {}

for key in ['aapl', 'csco', 'ibm', 'amzn']:
    name = 'WIKI/'+ key + '.11'
    data[key] = quandl.get(name, start_date=start, end_date=end)

# Then you can use it like
data['aapl'].DoSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inames = ['aapl', 'csco', 'ibm', 'amzn']
data = {name: quandl.get('WIKI/'+ name + '.11', start_date=start, end_date=end) for name in inames}
```

Comment: I am getting the following problem. Where the loop is working but it doesn't seem to be actually creating the new data frame using the name in the loop

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'aapl' is not defined

Comment: did you check that the string concatenation delivers the expected path? can you attach code?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! All you have to do is enclose the list elements in strings.

What you are doing now:

```
a = 'WIKI/'+ i + '.11'                  # Where i is an object, probably a pointer/instance
```

What you need to do:

```
a = 'WIKI/'+ i + '.11'                  # Where i is a good-old-happy string
```

So, your code your code should look something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import quandl

start = pd.to_datetime('2012-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')


# You have to add Strings to calculate i (But, you are adding objects)
L = ["aap1", "csco", "ibm", "amzn"]
L_i = []
for i in L:
    a = 'WIKI/'+ i + '.11'
    i = quandl.get(a, start_date=start, end_date=end)
    # Then do whatever you want with the i-s : L_i.append(i)
```